# Usage of too while comparing two places

Tags: word-usage, american-english, speech, subcontinental-english

While in a conversation about a place `xyz` which is facing water scarcity, if another place `abc` is also having water scarcity, which sentence would be correct:-

I know `xyz` has water scarcity, but is `abc` **too** having water scarcity?

I know `xyz` has water scarcity, but is `abc` having water scarcity **too**?

Comment: It's not a matter of "correct" - just idiomatic preference. Which favours ["Are they going too?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+they+going+too%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) over ["Are they too going?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+they+too+going%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @FumbleFingers hey thats right thanks. Well , then which one would you idiomatically prefer?

Comment: That's a tricky question! For some "either is valid" usages, I have my own strong preference (almost always in favour of *the most common form*). In this particular case I have no real objection to the less common form apart from the very *fact* that it's less common. So although I'd *normally* follow common practice, sometimes I might deliberately choose the "slightly exotic" version to convey some subtle nuance or emphasis. Unlike you, I have no concerns that anyone might think I'm not fully conversant with what constitutes "valid English", so I can use the language more "freely".

Answer (score 1):

> I know xyz has water scarcity, but is abc having water scarcity too?

This is the more correct usage.

You can put `too` closer to the noun in certain cases, but it is limited and tends to sound more aloof.

"abc too suffers from water scarcity." for example. In these cases `also` is more natural and understood.

Comment: but then wouldn't that mean, that `abc` is having water scarcity along with something else? I mean the same sense as in here: There is a lot of pollution in `abc`. And `abc` has water scarcity too.

Comment: @beginer - not in this context.

Comment: @Telastyn: We don't know the full context. It's possible that OP's question arose after a lengthy discussion about the fact that abc is suffering from extreme soil erosion and other restraints on crop production, in which case one might reasonably interpret ***too*** there as meaning *in addition abc's other agricultural problems*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I suppose, but in that case changing the position of too isn't going to do much in clarifying the ambiguity.

Comment: Well, per my comment to the question, I don't really endorse your "more correct" classification (as opposed to "more common"). But it seems to me if you *do* opt for the less common position, you're linking ***too*** more strongly to the preceding *abc* rather than *water scarcity*. Which effectively *does* remove any ambiguity, since that's the most obvious reason why you might have chosen to use slightly non-standard phrasing (assuming you're a native speaker).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes, in my experience as a native American English speaker, too will contrast the first part of the sentence when the sentence is conjoined. In my experience, too is used almost universally at the end of the sentence in those contexts. "Are they too going?" sounds very awkward and ungrammatical to me.

Comment: @Telastyn: The question here tends to put us in mind of "correct/incorrect", because it's being asked by a non-native speaker who's presumably only interested in "most common usage". But if I put that aside (because this is *ELU*, not ELL), I don't see anything inherently unacceptable about relocating ***too***. I just assume that if a *native speaker* uses a relatively uncommon form, they must have some reason other than simply not speaking English very well. Which naturally causes me to look for whatever subtle nuance they might be intending to convey.